# How to find a constant that makes a geometric series convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For this question, I'm stuck on finding a constant that will make the series convergent. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

Find all positive values of the constant b for which the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b^{ln(n)}$ is convergent.

|b| has to be less than one in order for the series to be convergent.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b^{ln(n)} = \frac{1}{1-b}$

$ 1 = \frac{1}{1-b}$

$1(1-b)= 1$

$b=2$

Comment: I don't follow your logic. Why is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b^{\ln n}$ equal to $\frac{1}{1-b}$? And why do you then set this equal to $1$?

Comment: Geometric?  Are you sure this is geometric??

Comment: Hint: $b^{\ln(n)} = n^{\ln(b)}$.

Comment: Check your question id say

Comment: It looks like a geometric series

Comment: Check the *definition* of geometric series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b^{ln(n)}
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{\ln (b)ln(n)}
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{\ln (b) }
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{n^{-\ln (b) }}
$
which converges for
$-\ln(b) > 1$
or
$\ln(b) < -1$
or
$b < 1/e$.